# How to clone a workspace in perforce

Tags: perforce

How to clone my co-worker's workspace in perforce? I have the name of the workspace to clone from, how can I do it? I have tried doing it via command line with
'p4 client -t coworker_workspace_name', but I get this error 'Client '?coworker_workspace_name' doesn't exit.

Thank you.

Comment: It shows up in 'p4 clients', but you can't use it in 'p4 client -t'? Weird. What if you try 'p4 client -o coworker_workspace_name'? Also, try using your mouse to exactly copy-and-paste the workspace name from 'p4 clients' to 'p4 client -t', in case you made a simple typo.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this via the P4V GUI client.  I would post a screenshot, but I need at least 10 reputation :'(

1. Go to the Workspaces tab.
2. If you don't see it, you can show it via "View -> Workspaces"
3. Untick the filtering options, such as "Show only workspaces available or use on this computer" (see figure). You should see your co-worker's workspace (assuming it's on the same Perforce server you're connected to).
4. Right-click it and select "Create/Update Workspace from '...'"
5. Select the "Create Workspace" radio button to create a new workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Using linux/bash command line:

p4 client -o -t *source_client*  *target_client_name* | sed 's,Root.*,Root:\t*desired path*,' | p4 client -i

`p4 client -o -t source_client target_client_name`
Copies source_client and changes any reference to its name to "target_client_name".
E.g. All references of "clientA" become "clientB"

`sed 's,Root.\*,Root\:\tDesired_Root_Path,'`
Replace "Desired_Root_Path" with wherever you'd like your Root directory.  I like to group my workspaces into "/workarea/allmyworkspaces/" so that's what I'd supply.
The commas are the separators for the sed command.

`p4 client -i`
Reads a client spec from standard input, so this pipes all the output from the previous commands into a spec creation.
To test that your values will be correct, leave this portion off the command and everything will print to stdout and you can inspect.

Comment: Great answer! I edited this to remove the escape \ in front of the * in the `sed 's,Root.*,Root\:\tDesired_Root_Path,'` command. The original sed command `sed 's,Root.\*,Root\:\tDesired_Root_Path,'` with the backslash in front of the * in that regexp was preventing it from changing. Note also that Root is part of the p4 client -o output. Just FYI.